# How can i link an xsl page into my php page?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a xml page that includes PHP in it, therefore its called xml.php

I have also created a XSL Style Sheet that will style my xml.php page

However i need to link the xsl page into my php page. I cannot use

```
"<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLT.xsl"?>
```

because my page is .php?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Load the XML source
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('collection.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('collection.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);

?>
```

Comment: I do not hot a XML page. I have a PHP and xsl. The php page is my Xml page however it contains pulling data out of a SQL table therefore requires PHP so has to be .php?

Comment: Point this 'collection.xml' to your php page

Comment: Or then why the hassle of xml and xslt, make it a html-document in the first place.

Comment: i changed the collection to the php page and it still does not work :( I get the style but no data